# how to include php file in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a login controller that has a function that connects to LDAP using my domain credentials.

```
class Login extends MX_Controller {

const USER = "DOMAINACCOUNT";
const PASS = "DoM@inP@ssw0rd";

public function checkWW930() {
    $ldapserver = "ldap://ww930.sampledomain.net";
    $dn = 'dc=ww930,dc=sampledomain,dc=net';
    $ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapserver) or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");
    //ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    //ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    $user = self::USER;
    $pass = self::PASS;
    $bind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn, 'ww930\\'.$user, $pass);
    $filter = "(samaccountname=". $this->input->post('username') .")";
    $result = ldap_search($ldapconn, $dn, $filter);
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
    if($info["count"] > 0) {
        return TRUE;    // account exists in ww930 domain
    } else {
        return FALSE;   // account does not exist in ww930 domain
    }
```

This works fine but I would like to save my credentials in a separate file so I can use it in other controllers if needed. Also I want to save it in a single file so that if my password expires, I only have to update one file. I am thinking to put my credentials in credentials.php file then add include('credentials.php'); Can someone help me how to implement it? Many thanks.

Comment: in CI structure, there is `constants.php`, in that you can define all the constants.

Comment: can you show me how? and how to access the variables from the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your constants in `/config/constants.php`

by adding this two lines at the end of the file

```
defined('USER')      OR define('USER', "DOMAINACCOUNT");
defined('PASS')      OR define('PASS', "DoM@inP@ssw0rd");
```

Now you can use your constants where ever you want in your project.

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this in order to abstract and organize your structure

create in your application/config/ folder a new file named ldap.php

and put the following code in it

```
$config["ldap_default"] = array(
    "server"  =>  "ldap://ww930.sampledomain.net",
    "dn"  =>  "dc=ww930,dc=sampledomain,dc=net",
    "user" => "DOMAINACCOUNT",
    "password"  => "DoM@inP@ssw0rd",
);
```

create a library called CustomLDAPConnection.php (put it in your application/libraries folder)

```
class CustomLDAPConnection
{
    private $ci;
    private $arrConfig = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci = &get_instance();
        $this->ci->load->config("ldap");
    }

    public function checkWW930($userName = false, $configGroup = "default") 
    {
        if (!$userName) return false;

        $this->arrConfig = $this->ci->config->item("ldap_".$configGroup);

        $ldapconn = ldap_connect($this->arrConfig['server']) or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");
        $bind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn, 'ww930\\'.$this->arrConfig['user'], $arrConfig['password']);
        $filter = "(samaccountname=". $userName .")";

        //ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        //ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
        $result = ldap_search($ldapconn, $this->arrConfig['dn'], $filter);
        $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
        return ($info["count"] > 0) ?   true    :   false;
    }
}
```

and then in your Login Controller

```
class Login extends MX_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library("CustomLDAPConnection");
    }

    public function checkLDAPForUser()
    {
        return $this->CustomLDAPConnection->checkWW930($this->input->post("username"));
    }
}
```

its very basic and simple but it should give you the hint you need

Comment: it can be worked, but no need to do this long process. just define constants in `constants.php` file

Comment: since user credentials or any other authentication data are pretty much always dynamic i think its really bad practice to define constants here

Comment: then what you did?? created a library and all!!!!!!! but the simple solution is just define constant and give values